# What causes Google gcloud error message "ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'gcloud'" and how to resolve this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a cloud function in GCP using `CI-CD` process. I have written a yaml file. Below is my code:
cloudbuild.yaml

```
# Deploy Cloud Function
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    id: deploy
    dir: "/workspace/API/audit_from_storage"
    args:
      [
        'gcloud', 'functions', 'deploy', 'audit_deployed',
        '--set-env-vars', 'BASEURL=${_CP_BASE_URL},BUCKETNAME=${_BUCKETNAME},FUNCTION=${_FUNCTION}',
        '--region=us-central1',
        '--source=.',
        '--trigger-resource=${_BUCKETNAME}',
        '--trigger-event=google.storage.object.finalize',
        '--runtime=nodejs10',
        '--entry-point=collectAudit',
        '--service-account=${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}',
      ]
```

Below are the logs:

```
Finished Step #0 - "installing_npm"
Starting Step #1 - "deploy"
Step #1 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'gcloud'.
Step #1 - "deploy": Maybe you meant:
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud functions deploy
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud run deploy
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments cancel-preview
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments create
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments describe
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments list
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments stop
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud deployment-manager deployments update
Step #1 - "deploy": 
Step #1 - "deploy": To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
Step #1 - "deploy":   gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
Finished Step #1 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
```

Please help me resolve this.
Below is the script after removing the `gcloud` argument from the array list:

`Edit:`

```
# Deploy Cloud Function
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  id: deploy
  dir: "/workspace/API/audit_from_storage"
  args:
    [
      'functions', 'deploy', 'audit_from_storage',
      '--set-env-vars', 'BASEURL=${_CP_BASE_URL},BUCKETNAME=${_BUCKETNAME},FUNCTION=${_FUNCTION}',
      '--region=us-central1',
      '--source=.',
      '--trigger-resource=${_BUCKETNAME}',
      '--trigger-event=google.storage.object.archive',
      '--runtime=nodejs10',
      '--entry-point=collectAudit',
      '--service-account=${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}',
    ]
```

Below are the logs:

```
Starting Step #1 - "deploy"
Step #1 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) could not parse resource []
Finished Step #1 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

[image]

Thanks
Pritish

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `gcloud` in the args array; it's the entrypoint for the container.

So, just:

```
args: ["functions","deploy",...]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, but getting this error:
`"deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) could not parse resource []`

Comment: Can you share more context? Where do you run this command? Where is your code? What your project structure?

Comment: Could you also post updated the yaml file that you're trying to deploy after the change that was suggested by DazWilkin?

Comment: Hi, see my 'Edit' section.

Comment: I have also added my project structure. My code is in `bitbucket` repository. I have mirrored this repository in my `google cloud source repository`.

Comment: it seems that you're missing the `--zone` parameter, try to run the `gcloud` command outside of the cloud-build (in a console) and deploy the cloud function to verify if all the parameters that are being sent are enough to build it correctly